# Meteor 1.7.0.5 : Taking more then 40 Sec time to call API

Tags: meteor

In Meteor.js App while performing Meteor call method from client side taking too much time to connect meteor call method server side .

1. we use Meteor 1.7.0.5
2. MongoDB server version: 3.6.4

> Clent side:

```
searchListData()
{
        console.log("searchDataVal",this.state.searchDataVal);
        console.log("Time Stamp",new Date());
        Meteor.call("getTestData",this.state.searchDataVal,(err,res)=>{
            if(err){}else{
                console.log("==>",res);
                console.log("res ",new Date());

                this.setState({
                    searchData : res,
                });
            }
        });
}
```

> Server side =

```
'getTestData':function(searchDataVal){
         
          console.log(" Time Stamp ",new Date());
           
          console.log("search ",searchDataVal);
           
          var data = Details.find({$or:[{Number:searchDataVal},{Name:searchDataVal}]},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch();
            
            return data;
                
}
```

> Result Client side

```
searchListData /(?=.*00495).+/i

 Time Stamp  Thu Mar 25 2021 17:44:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 
 ==> true 
 res  Thu Mar 25 2021 17:45:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

> result Server Side

```
 Time Stamp 2021-03-25T 17:45:39.622Z
 search  /(?=.*00495).+/i
```

Comment: The method and db call look fairly simple and ok. Maybe for starters try to optimize the MongoDB setup using indexes and see if it improves things.

Comment: How long does it take to evaluate that same query in a mongodb shell directly? It's almost certainly the culprit. How many documents are in that collection?

Comment: My first guess would be that the collection is large and the sort operator's target field (createdAt) is not indexed. By the way, the faster solution to get the latest documents is using `{ hint: { $natural: -1 } }` which inverts the cursor direction from last to first.

Comment: In mongodb shell query result  get immediately, near about 3k documents are in that collection

Comment: 3k documents should not take long to fetch, unless each one is big? Or is the regex you are using to search expensive?

Comment: Yes, Right I used regex.